# Seaborn heatmap ticks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a heatmap from a dataframe using seaborn. Somehow, whatever I try, the ytick labels are all ending up in the same position and overlapping, instead of spread out along the axis. This is my code:

```
df3=df2.loc[200:250]
yticks = np.linspace(200,250,5)
plt.figure(figsize=(18,3))
ax= sns.heatmap(df3,vmin=0,vmax=2,cmap='hsv_r',cbar_kws={"ticks":[0,1,2]},yticklabels=yticks)
plt.ylabel('Cross-shore distance [m]')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

This is how the y-axis looks: 
[image]

You can see all the ytick labels are in the top left corner on top of each other. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Can you maybe post a part of df3, so someone can check your code more thoroughly?

Comment: Can you first explain what you are trying to achieve? If you leave out `yticklabels` it should work as expected.

Comment: df3 is indexed with floats ranging from 200 until 250, however with each index there are a lot of decimals. I'd like to get my y-axis to not display all these decimals and at strange intervals (e.g. it goes from 200.14869184 to 207.6517499), but rather a cleanly spaced y-axis with no decimals and intervals of 10 (200,210,220,230,240,250). Leaving out yticklabels does plot the labels in the correct locations, but not according to my previously defined wishes.

Comment: Seaborn heatmap plots categorical data. Here it seems you want to plot numeric data. Hence better use a `pyplot.pcolormesh` plot. (Note that I could provide an answer with code if there was a [mcve] in the question.)